# Chef and Dolls MISSP

Tags: c

Here is the [link](https://www.codechef.com/problems/MISSP) to the codechef problem - Chef and Dolls

Why does my code always print the wrong answer? The output should be the number which doesn't have a match but my code always print the first element. Coudn't get the conditions right, what should be the condition?

**Problem Statement**

Chef is fan of pairs and he likes all things that come in pairs. He even has a doll collection in which all dolls have paired.One day while going through his collection he found that there are odd number of dolls. Someone had stolen a doll!!!

Help chef find which type of doll is missing..

**Input**
The first line contains the number of test cases. 
Second line of the input contains the number of elements in the array. 
The next n lines are the types of each doll that is left.

**Output**
Find the type of doll that doesn't have a pair

**Example**
Input:

1

3

1

2

1

Output:
2

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int t, N, i, m, k, z, flag=0;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {   
        scanf("%d",&N);
        int arr[N];
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
        int j;
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            m=arr[j];
            for(k=0;k<N;k++){
                if(m==arr[k] && k!=j)
                {
                    flag=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
                printf("%d", m);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide at least a summary of all needed information in your question itself. Also give sample input, current output and desired output. Then please describe the difference between the outputs in your words and try to reflect that difference on your code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It's suspicious that the innermost loop sets `flag`, but nothing ever checks its value.

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You break out of your loop everytime `k==j`. You have to check for every array member if it is present somewhere else in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t, N, i, j, k, m, z, flag;

    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t--)
    {   
        scanf("%d",&N);
        int arr[N];

        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
                scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }

        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            m=arr[j];
            flag=1;
            for(k=0;k<N;k++)
            {
                if(m==arr[k] && k!=j)
                {
                    flag=0;
                }
            }

            if(flag)
            {
                printf("%d\n", m);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But be careful as this only looks if an array member has a duplicate in it. You probably want to check if there is an even number of elements in the array.

If you want to check which array members occur an odd number of times

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t, N, i, j, k, m, z, num, flag;

    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t--)
    {   
        scanf("%d",&N);
        int arr[N], odds[N], n_odds;

        for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
                scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }

        n_odds=0;
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            m=arr[j];

            num=0;
            for(k=0;k<N;k++)
            {
                if(m==arr[k])
                {
                    num++;
                }
            }

            if(num%2) //occurs an odd number of times
            {
                flag=1;
                for(i=0;i<n_odds;i++)
                {
                    if(m==odds[i]) //has already been checked
                    {
                        flag=0;
                    }
                }

                if(flag)
                {
                    printf("%d\n", m);
                    odds[n_odds++]=m;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No there are always odd number of dolls

Comment: what does this mean?

`if(flag)
            {
                printf("%d\n", m);
            }`

Comment: @hemantvikaspatnaik You are searching the array for duplicates. If a duplicate exists you set `flag` to 0. `if(flag)` means if the flag is still set, there is no duplicate in the array, therefore it only occurs one time.

Comment: @hemantvikaspatnaik As i mentioned you should probably look for the members which occur an odd number of time in an array. I will edit my answer to include this case.

Comment: Yes please waiting

Comment: @hemantvikaspatnaik Second version should print all numbers which occur an odd amount of times once.

Comment: Any way of doing it without counting the odd occurrence, only by comparisons. The approach i took